# How can I merge javascript code with html form that triggers when we perform some action like "submit" and gives output?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a function using switch case in javascript.

```
function convert(x){
    switch(x) {case "c": return "d"; case "a": return "o"; case "t": return "g";} 
}
var str = "cat";
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    result += convert(str[i]) ;
}
console.log(result);
```

In this program,I gave default value of `str = "cat"` which gives output 
 dog. But instead of passing default value, I want to pass value via html form and print output. So I created a simple html form.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
      function showOutput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label><b>Please give your input: </b></label>
      <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
    </form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="showOutput();"><br/>
    <label>Your output is : </label>
    <p><span id='display'></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The layout of this HTML form is shown.
[image]

Now I want to input value as "cat " and when I click submit, I want output as "dog" using javascript code which I created earlier that has the "convert" function.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the loop inside the `showOutput` function so it will convert the user inputs and display the result in `display` span when the button is clicked.

**NOTE 1:** I suggest the use of `addEventListener()` instead of inline-event `onClick` when you attach events like :

```
document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', showOutput, false);
```

**NOTE 2:** You may need to put the submit input inside the form to validate the structure of your HTML code, you could also use `.textContent` attribute instead of `.innerHTML` since you're just assigning text and no HTML code.

```js
document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', showOutput, false);

function showOutput() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var str = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += convert(str[i]);
  }

  document.getElementById('display').textContent = result;
}

function convert(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case "c":
      return "d";
    case "a":
      return "o";
    case "t":
      return "g";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><b>Please give your input: </b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<br/>
<label>Your output is : </label>
<p><span id='display'></span></p>
```

Comment: Please If any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the code inside `showOutput()`. Then assign the returned result from the function to the element.

I will also suggest you to use [`textContent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML()` when dealing with text only content as it is faster, safer, and more predictable.

```js
function showOutput() {
  var str = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    result += convert(str[i]) ;
  } 
  document.getElementById('display').textContent = result;           
}
    
function convert(x){
  switch(x) {
    case "c": return "d"; 
    case "a": return "o"; 
    case "t": return "g";
  } 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><b>Please give your input: </b></label>
  <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showOutput();"><br/>
<label>Your output is : </label>
<p><span id='display'></span></p>
```